# VueJS show input field conditionally

Tags: vue.js

I have a button 'Add Field' and when I click it, I show a select box with several predefined options.

Now, below this select box I want to display another select box if the value selected in the select field is equal to, let's say, 'Hello', otherwise display an input field but I am struggling to achieve this.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
<div v-for="option in folder.salary.fields" :key="option.id">
    <b-form-group label="Select field" label-for="salaryOptionField">
       <select
                v-model="folder.salary.fields.name"
                value-field="id"
                @change="onOptionSelected"
        >
            <option :value="null" disabled>Select type</option>
            <option v-for="(type, key) in salaryFields" :value="key">
                {{ salaryFields[key] }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <template v-if="folder.salary.fields.name === 'Hello'">
            <b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name">
                <input type="text"
                       name="name"
                       v-model="folder.salary.benefits.a"
                       required/>
            </b-form-group>
        </template>
    </b-form-group>
</div>

<b-btn @click="addNewSalaryField" variant="primary">Add Field</b-btn>

addNewSalaryField(){
    this.folder.salary.fields.push({
        name: '',
          amount: ''
             })
}

data() {
     return {
        folder: {
          pages: [],
             salary: {
               fields: [],
               benefits: []
             }
           }
        }
    }
```

Right now, if I select 'Hello' from the select field, nothing happens. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `folder.salary.fields` is used as array and as object. Also, you are missing default value in `data()`. You need to fix that. Also, your select has `v-model="folder.salary.fields.name`, but also an event `@change="onOptionSelected"` that "destroys" value of `folder.salary.fields` (as it's using it as array). Did you get any errors in devtools console?

Comment: No, no errors. I feel quite lost with it. How should I approach this? What default value should I set?

Comment: I've figured the issue out. I changed to `v-model="option.name"`